# Spring boot MVC not starting up

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using SpringBoot 2.5.0 for my web application.  When I start up tomcat,  nothing happens.  At all.  catalina.out says it deployed the war, but no other clue as to it actually starting up.
I have this in my pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
</dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

And this is my main Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.xxx")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
ServletContext servletContext;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args );
}


@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    System.out.println("Testing STDOUT");
    logger.debug("Testing logger");
    WebApplicationContext rootAppContext = createRootApplicationContext(servletContext);
    this.servletContext = servletContext;
    if (rootAppContext != null) {
        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    }
    else {
        logger.debug("No ContextLoaderListener registered, as "
                + "createRootApplicationContext() did not "
                + "return an application context");
    }   
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("onApplicationEvent Testing STDOUT");
}
```

I would expect at the very least the System.out to print to the logs. But I have nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two things:
1. System.out.println("Testing STDOUT"); will print in console logs and not in any log file.
 2. logger.debug("Testing logger"); will print in debug level only. You can try making it info level and  check.

Comment: try putting "debug=true" in your application.properties file to see the whole log message of failure